# Expectation of the operator norm of projection of a random permutation matrix

Tags: matrices, random-matrices, eigenvalues, permutations, random-permutations

Assuming I have a fixed dimension $p$ subspace of $\mathbb{R}^d$ orthogonal to $1^d$ and $VV^\top$ with $V \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times p}$ is the orthogonal projection to the subspace.
What bound can I reach on $\mathbb{E}_P[\|\|V^\top PV\|\|_2]$ with $P$ being a random permutation matrix?

I can now get a $O(p/\sqrt{n})$ bound using the following way, $$(\mathbb{E}_P[\|\|V^\top PV\|\|_2])^2 \le \mathbb{E}_P[\|\|V^\top PV\|\|_2^2] = \mathbb{E}_P[\lambda_1 (V^\top P VV^\top P V)] \le \mathbb{E}_P[\mathrm{Tr} (V^\top P VV^\top P V)]$$
and then explicitly calculate the final expectation. But I think in the last inequality here I may lose a factor of $p$ and suspect that in fact this value can be upper bounded by $O(\sqrt{p/n})$ (which seems to be the case when $P$ is a random rotation matrix).

Comment: Is that the spectral norm?

Comment: What exactly is $\|\|V^\top PV\|\|_2$?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion.